# Help solve $2 \sin^{2}x=2+\cos x$

Tags: calculus

Solve $2 \sin^{2}(x)=2+\cos x$. I tried to get both in terms of $\cos x$ but where do I go from there?

Answer (score 7):

**Hint:** Replace $\sin^2 x$ by $1-\cos^2 x$. You end up with a quadratic equation for $\cos x$.

The equation is in this case very simple. It is $2-2\cos^2 x=2+\cos x$. Be careful not to lose some solutions!

Comment: Upvote for the hint. It was starting to look like answers.yahoo in here! (I.e. lots of high-rep users answering - at times with full solutions - within a few minutes of the OP)

Comment: Alas the hint repeats the thing the OP claims to have done, and tells him to solve the thing the OP says he doesn't know how to do. But hopefully the keyword "quadratic equation" triggers something....

Comment: @Hurkyl: I thought OP might have done it wrong, and that the sight of the equation n black and white, coming from somebody else, would trigger a response.

Answer (score 2):

$$\sin^2x=1-\cos^2x\implies 2+\cos x=2\sin^2x=2-2\cos^2x\implies$$

$$2\cos x\left(\cos x+\frac{1}{2}\right)=0\implies \cos x = 0\;\;\vee\;\;\cos x = -\frac{1}{2}\ldots$$

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$2 \sin^2(x) = 2 + \cos(x) \implies 2(1-\sin^2(x)) + \cos(x) = 0 \implies 2 \cos^2(x) + \cos(x) = 0$$

> This gives us$$\cos(x)(2\cos(x)+1)=0 \implies \cos(x) = 0 \text{ or }-\dfrac12$$Hence, we get that$$x = n \pi + \dfrac{\pi}2 \text{ or } (2n+1) \pi \pm \dfrac{\pi}3$$where $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @Cowardly down-voter: Reason for down-vote.

Comment: [Be nice](http://math.stackexchange.com/faq#etiquette). There is no requirement that people explain their votes, so asking politely might get a response.

Comment: @robjohn I don't think these cowards will reply back, even if I ask them in a polite manner.

Comment: If you didn't think you would get a response, then why did you ask?

Comment: @Hurkyl In a **hope** that the coward, if he has some self-respect (which is also equally unlikely), will respond.

Comment: Whether the person who downvoted you replies or not, it is not appropriate to call them a coward.

Comment: @robjohn I believe it equally (if not more) inappropriate to down-vote a question without giving a valid reason.

Comment: Then we're right back to the suggestion that politely asking has a better chance of getting a response. I will add that if I was at the point where I was strongly considering starting to downvote answers that just give the steps in a ready-to-submit form with little explanation, your reaction would have definitely have given me the final push start doing so.

Comment: @Hurkyl Feel free to do whatever you like. I do not really care.

Comment: @user17762: I appreciate getting an explanation for any downvotes, and to me a downvote without an explanation is not terribly useful. However, voting on Stackexchange is anonymous, so it is not required of a downvoter to leave an explanation.

Comment: @robjohn It is also not required (according to US law) to be nice.

Comment: @robjohn: Hurkyl has provided a useful and reasonable explanation. :)

Comment: @TheChaz2.0: and I have been told that I am not required to be nice :-)

Answer (score 0):

$2(1-\cos^2(x)) = 2 + \cos(x)$. So

$2\cos^{2}(x)+\cos(x) = \cos(x)(2\cos(x)+1) = 0$. This implies that

$\cos(x) = 0$  or $\cos(x) = -1/2$.